# How to search for a value in multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to search through multiple columns. Then, if any of the values in the columns equals a condition, then I need to extract the value in the column to the left of the column searched.

Below is a sample of my code. I am searching the `congress_1` and `congress_2` columns for the value `108`. If there are any such matches, then I need to extract the value in `position_1` and `position_2` respectively.

```
a2 <- data.frame(position_1 = c("Senator", "Rep", "Senator", "Rep"),
                 congress_1 = c(107, 107, 108, 109),
                 position_2 = c("Senator", "Rep", "Senator", "Rep"),
                 congress_2 = c(108, 108, 109, 110))
```

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
row position_108
1   "Senator"
2   "Senator"
3   "Rep"
4   "none"
```

I've been trying to use the `which()` function, but the issue is that I have a large data frame and there are many columns that I need to searched through. Because of the nature of my question, I do think that I need to use the `ifelse()` function. The challenge I've been having is how to extract the data to the left of the column if there is a match.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can 108 be present several times in the same row, across the columns that are to be searched?

Comment: Thank you for the question! Yes, you assumed correctly: 108 cannot be present several times in the same row across the columns that are to be searched. However, it can be present multiple times in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` with `if`

```
position_108 <- sapply(1:nrow(a2) , \(x) if(a2$congress_1[x] == 108)
    a2$position_1[x] else if(a2$congress_2[x] == 108)
        a2$position_1[x] else "none")

ans <- data.frame(position_108)

ans

#>  position_108
#> 1      Senator
#> 2          Rep
#> 3      Senator
#> 4         none
```

Answer (score 0):

Does transmute with case_when do what you need?

```
library(dplyr)
a2 %>%
  transmute(answer = case_when(congress_1 == 108 ~ position_1,
                               congress_2 == 108 ~ position_2))

   answer
1 Senator
2     Rep
3 Senator
4    <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 108 cannot be present several times in the same row across the columns that are to be searched, we can use the approach below. The solution is generalized in the sense that you get around having to type the variable names (in case you have very many).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a2 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_transform = ~ as.character(.)) %>%
  mutate(row = str_sub(name, -1) < lag(str_sub(name, -1)),
         row = replace_na(row, F),
         row = cumsum(row),
         position_108 = if_else(value == 108, lag(value), NA_character_),
         id = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  filter((! F %in% is.na(position_108) & id == min(id)) |
          ! is.na(position_108)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(position_108)

# # A tibble: 4 × 1
#   position_108
#   <chr>       
# 1 Senator     
# 2 Rep         
# 3 Senator     
# 4 NA
```

I can't help thinking that I have dug myself into a hole on this one, though. Views are more than welcome.